# Is there a way to ask udisksctl to list all partitions and block devices?

Tags: udisks

I saw https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200960/find-all-storage-devices-attached-to-a-linux-machine#201091 and while that is cool, I am/was wondering if it can be similarly achieved by using udisksctl. It should as the help gives enough indication -

```
[$] udisksctl help

Usage:
  udisksctl COMMAND

Commands:
  help            Shows this information
  info            Shows information about an object
  dump            Shows information about all objects
  status          Shows high-level status
  monitor         Monitor changes to objects
  mount           Mount a filesystem
  unmount         Unmount a filesystem
  unlock          Unlock an encrypted device
  lock            Lock an encrypted device
  loop-setup      Set-up a loop device
  loop-delete     Delete a loop device
  power-off       Safely power off a drive
  smart-simulate  Set SMART data for a drive

Use "udisksctl COMMAND --help" to get help on each command.
```

Using

```
[$] udisksctl status /dev/sd
```

does give you list of all hard disks, pen-drives/SSD's etc but not partitions. Any ideas ?

Comment: Why do you want to use `udisksctl` for that when you have `lsblk` ?

Answer (score 3):

```
for disk in /dev/sd[a-z] /dev/sd[a-z][a-z]; do
  if test -b $disk; then
    echo; echo ------------------ Disk $disk ------------------
    udisksctl info -b $disk
    for partition in $disk[1-9] $disk[0-9][0-9]; do
      if test -b $partition; then
        echo; echo ------------------ Partition $partition ------------------
        udisksctl info -b $partition
      fi
    done
  fi
done
```

Comment: ah, so it will need a script, was afraid of that. Was thinking it might be something simpler.

Comment: Not all scripts are files... Just copy everything and paste it into the terminal. You may want to add `| less` at the end.